# How to configure build path entries in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am new to springMVC. In below image iam getting 2 build path entries missing. how to get arround this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmmYv.png)

Comment: It looks those directories are just not created. Have you tried creating them in filesystem?

Comment: Are you using maven (or not)?

Comment: yeah i am using maven

Answer (score 0):

The two questions in comments are very relevant.

What we see in the picture is that the "src/main/java" and "src/test/java" directories simply don't exist, although the "src/main/resources" directory does exist.

If you're constructing a Java application using Maven, the Java source code that gets deployed goes in "src/main/java".  If you have your Java source code somewhere else, you should move it to that directory.